# How To Perform Remote Validation in MVC4 Without Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a web application using MVC without Entity Framework. In my application, I want to perform remote validation to check whether user name already exist or not.I read many blogs about remote validation. In most of the blogs they use entity framework data model to do this whereas I wish to use sql command for that. However I can't achieve the desired validation.

Here is my code:
Model,Controller,View code.

Mode:

```
public class RemoteValidation
{

    [Remote("ValidateUserName","Test",ErrorMessage="UserName Already Exist")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RemoteValidation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoteValidation(RemoteValidation rv)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into AdminSignup (UserName,Password) Values ('"+rv.UserName+"','"+rv.Password+"')", conn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }

        return View();
    }



    public JsonResult ValidateUserName(string UserName)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select*from AdminSignup Where UserName='"+UserName+"'", conn);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            {
                return Json("User Name Already Exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
            }
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

View:

```
@model TestMvc.Models.RemoteValidation
```

```
<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserName)

        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Password)
        </div>        
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Check" />
            </div>
    }
</body>
```

I don't know why i can't get output Any One please help me and Suggest how to acheive this..

Comment: Apart from the fact that your have exposed yourself to [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), what problem are you having? Have you included the relevant scripts for client side validation? Are you hitting the controller method?

Comment: Yes i include script files for client side validation in view  but i can't get valiadtion message..and also modelstate.isvalid get true !

Comment: Do you hit the `ValidateUserName()` method?

Comment: And `ModelState` will always be true - `RemoteAttribute` is client side validation only and you have no other validation attributes on your properties

Comment: No how to get it?

Comment: Then you have either disabled client side validation, or you have not included the relevant scripts (or have them in the wrong order)

Comment: @santhosh Did you see any errors in browser console if you use developer tools (F12)?

Comment: @Santhosh If you put a break point on `ValidateUserName(...)` action, is it hitting? Is your controller decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute? If yes, ideally it should not hit the action unless you logged in. Did you try decorating `ValidateUserName(...)` with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

Comment: No that ValidateUserName(...)  action is  not hitting. @SivaGopal

Comment: @santhosh Are you using POST/GET to call that action method? Based on that try decorating action method with either `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]` and check if break point is hitting. Also check all those questions I asked in my first & second comments and provide an update to help us understand the issue.

Comment: Yes bro i used both Get and Post method but it not hit the ValidateUserName() action and i did not see any error in browser console @SivaGopal

Comment: I asked you to provide answers for all my questions but you are not doing so and leading to lengthy fragmented discussion and time!! Is your controller decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute? If no then fire up fiddler or browser network tab and check what is the response code you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your web.config to enable validation ?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Use your browsers developer tools to see what HTTP traffic is generated.

Please look at parameterised queries and SQLCommand - NEVER hand build SQL strings in web sites - it opens you to SQL injection attacks.